# Google Chrome - How to remove links in new tab site

Tags: google-chrome, privacy

How can I remove the links in the site which loads if I create a new tab?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hover over each icon, and a menu will appear.

[image]

Click the 3 `...` and then choose `Remove`

Alternatively, change the New Tab behaviour from chrome://settings/appearance